# Remove page name from post links

Tags: jquery, text, replace, href

So, I have a forum where links can be posted in topics. But I want my links only, not the hashtag links to change from `https://{FORUMNAME}.com/extensions` to simply `/extensions`.

HTML of a post to show you an example:

```
<div class="content">
  <a href="/tags/welcome" rel="nofollow">#Welcome</a>
  <a href="/">https://{FORUMNAME}.com/</a>
  <a href="/t20-topic">https://{FORUMNAME}.com/t20-topic</a>
  <a href="/shop">https://{FORUMNAME}.com/shop</a>
</div>
```

What I want it to show is links like this:

```
#Welcome
https://{FORUMNAME}.com/
/t20-topic
/shop
```

but if `https://{FORUMNAME}.com/` gets replaced by `/` it would work too.

I'd like this to be done using jQuery.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

So I managed to find a way to do it on my forum, but I'm wondering if there's an easier way to do that somehow.

Here's the script I used:

```
  $('.content a').addClass('postLinks');
  $('.content a[rel="nofollow"]').removeClass('postLinks');
  
  $('.content a.postLinks').text(function(){        
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace('https://{FORUMNAME}.com',''));
  });
  
  $('a.postLinks[href="/"]').text('/home');
```

Regards.